# Why are there two table views?

Tags: ratchet, ratchet-bootstrap, ratchet-2

In the [documentation](http://goratchet.com/components/#table-views), they have:

```
<li class="table-view-cell table-view-cell">Item 2</li>
```

Q: Was that just a typo, or did they put table-view-cell in there twice for some reason?

Comment: It looks like they referenced my issue in a commit and it should be resolved in the next release https://github.com/twbs/ratchet/commit/2967105bc482151be70864eff07a1bbf7ec893fe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the same thing the other day and was going to investigate... your question reminded me.

I created this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/4Nwe2/) and the duplicate class doesn't seem to apply any `CSS` rules, so I cannot image it serves a purpose.

I searched the issues submitted on GitHub and couldn't find one related to this so I submitted [this one](https://github.com/twbs/ratchet/issues/561). Hopefully that will get an answer or fix.

Comment: Wow. Github is revolutionizing software development.